# Create article preview in ModX?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources, modx-templates

How can I create preview of my articles(which are in the resource **"articles"**) using their `[[*description]]` and `[[*introtext]]` in the right sidebar on another resources page, called **"services"**(this page's (template) code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>[[++site_name]] - [[*pagetitle]]</title>
<base href="[[++site_url]]" />
</head>
<body>
[[*content]]

</body>
</html>
```

)

I created new tpl, called it **"article_story"** with this code:

```
<p><a href="[[++site_url]][[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]<br>
<img alt="[[+pagetitle]]" src="[[+tv.image:phpthumbof=`w=300`]]"></a><br>
[[+introtext]]<br>
</p>
```

I've tried to use this code:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`[[*id]]` &tpl=`article_story` &limit=`3` &sortby=`{"publishedon":"ASC","createdon":"DESC"}`]]
```

But it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the [getResources](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources) Extra doesn't include unpublished Resources. You need to add `&showUnpublished` to the snippet call:

```
[[!getResources? 
    &parents=`[[*id]]` 
    &tpl=`article_story`
    &showUnpublished=`1` 
    &limit=`3` 
    &sortby=`{"publishedon":"ASC","createdon":"DESC"}`
]]
```